# webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack.config.js

I am beginner to react js.  Please someone provide input for below issue.

In local system react js application is working fine but when i am generating build from Jenkins compilation is failing and its throwing below error.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers' in '/usr/src/app/src/component'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

 If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
 - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
 - install 'path-browserify'
 If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
 resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with react.